# How can I add a widget with data from a split board column?

Tags: azure-devops, reporting, dashboard, project-management, agile-project-management

I would like to have a widget showing me the evolution of how many US are in the Doing and Done split (or sub) columns per week on my azure board.

I have tried many ways but cannot seem to find the correct way to display this data. Would you know how to solve this ?

Many thanks !!

-Theo

[Example of data visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aaadd.png)

[Azure Split (or sub) board columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1VV9.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a widget that shows the evolution of count of work items in the Doing and Done split (or sub) columns **per week**.

For now this feature is **not supported** yet, as a workaround I suggest you can submit a feature request on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html  if you do want this feature. This is our User Voice forum and the team would consider your feedback seriously if it get enough votes.

[image]